# Javascript UTC Timestamp for current time and 3500 ms earlier

Tags: javascript, time

Please, someone tell me how to do this. I have tried every method I have found. Not getting anything to work. I don't want to import anything. I just need the current timestamp and 3500 ms earlier. This is for an API call

Here is where I'm at so far:

```
var current_date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Europe/London"});


var start_date = new Date();
start_date.setMinutes(start_date.getMinutes() - 3); // timestamp
start_date = new Date(start_date).getTime(); // Date object
```

Comment: 3500ms is 3.5 seconds. Not minutes.

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I'm looking for, unfortunately. Disregard the amount of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your API call takes a unix timestamp or an ISO-8601 string (or some other date format).
You can easily get the UTC time in both with native JavaScript date objects.

[Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) will always give us the time in milliseconds from the unix epoch, this is independent of the timezone we're calling it in. If you need the unix timestamp in seconds you can just divide by 1000.

Likewise [Date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) will give us the current UTC time in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format so this will be unambiguous too.

Adding an offset (in milliseconds) to a date is easy, just add/subtract your offset to the unix epoch offset (return of Date.getTime()), then pass to the Date constructor to get your offset date.

If you wish to send a US / GB etc. format string I'd suggest using [Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), you can use "UTC" as the timezone if you're following that approach.

If you want to create a custom UTC time string you can always use [Date.getUTCFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear),  [Date.getUTCMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth), [Date.getUTCDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) etc. and combine to create your date string.

```js
const locale = "en-us";
const currentTimeUnix = new Date().getTime();
const currentDate = new Date(currentTimeUnix );
console.log(`Current UTC time (unix, ms): ${currentTimeUnix}`);
console.log(`Current UTC time (unix, sec): ${Math.round(currentTimeUnix/1000)}`);
console.log(`Current UTC time (ISO-8601): ${currentDate.toISOString()}`);
console.log(`Current UTC time (locale format):`, currentDate.toLocaleString(locale, { timeZone: 'UTC' }));

const offsetMilliseconds = 3500;

// Subtract the offset from the current time
const offsetTimeUnix = currentTimeUnix - offsetMilliseconds;
const offsetDate = new Date(offsetTimeUnix);

console.log(`\nResults after subtracting offset (${offsetMilliseconds}ms):`);

console.log(`Offset UTC time (unix, ms): ${offsetTimeUnix}`);
console.log(`Offset UTC time (unix, sec): ${Math.round(offsetTimeUnix / 1000)}`);
console.log(`Offset UTC time (ISO-8601): ${offsetDate.toISOString()}`);
console.log(`Offset UTC time (locale format):`, offsetDate.toLocaleString(locale, { timeZone: 'UTC' }));

// NB: Month is zero-based in JavaScript
const customTimestamp = `${offsetDate.getUTCFullYear()}-${offsetDate.getUTCMonth() + 1}-${offsetDate.getUTCDate()} ${offsetDate.getUTCHours()}:${offsetDate.getUTCMinutes()}:${offsetDate.getUTCSeconds()}`;
console.log(`Offset UTC time (custom format):`, customTimestamp);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly easy to do.

From [Date.prototype.getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

> The **getTime()** method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch.
>
> * JavaScript uses *milliseconds* as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in *seconds*.
>
> *getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.*

Since JS uses a millisecond timestamp just get the timestamp of the current time (always UTC) and then subtract whatever number of milliseconds from it.

```js
let currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
let threePointFiveSecondsAgo = currentTimestamp - 3500;

// convert timestamp back in to a date.
let pastDate = new Date(threePointFiveSecondsAgo);
```